# Compare rows in pandas dataframe to determine matching non-matching patterns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with answers to exam questions of 1,000 students. Each row represents 1 student and the columns are the answers to the questions.

I would like to compare each student to the next then sum the number of questions they answered the same and the number the answered differently. I would then like the put put of the comparison to the identify the pairs and the totals of then answers that are the same and different

This is how far I got with the code to sum the correct answers

```
    def match(a,b):
         sum_cor=sum(np.logical_and(df.loc[a,]==df.loc[b,],df.loc[a,]==5))
         print(sum_cor)
```

Data

```
    Student   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8
       0       5   5     4    5   5  5   2    4
       1       5   3     5    5   5  5   2    2
       2       5   5     5    5   5  5   5    2
       3       5   1     5    5   5  5   5    5
       4       5   5     5    5   5  5   5    4
```

Output

```
      Row_1    Row_2  #_Match  #not_matched
       L00      L0      5         3
       L01      L1      5         3
       L02      L2      5         3
```

Comment: What does L00 and L0 represent?

Comment: @ScottBoston L00 and L0 represents the pairs of students that were compared to determine the #_Match and #non_matched

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand.  In your original dataframe I don't see an L00 no L0, L01, and L1.  I see the Students 0,1,2,3,4.  How do you generate L00?

Comment: @ScottBoston  For example the output will have Row_1 Student 0 (L00) and Row_2 Student 1 (L1) - this will allow us to identify the matched and non_matched for each student combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input:

```
         Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8
Student                                
0         5   5   4   5   5   5   2   4
1         5   3   5   5   5   5   2   2
2         5   5   5   5   5   5   5   2
3         5   1   5   5   5   5   5   5
4         5   5   5   5   5   5   5   4
```

Code:

```
def compare(d):
    return [sum(d == df.loc[i].values) for i in df.index]

df.set_index('Student', inplace=True)

answer = df.apply(compare, 1).apply(pd.Series)

answer = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[i, j, answer.loc[i, j]] for i in range(len(df))]) 
                    for j in range(len(df))])

answer = answer.rename(columns={0:'Row_1', 1:'Row_2', 2:'#_Match'})

answer['Row_1'] = 'L' + answer['Row_1'].astype(str)
answer['Row_2'] = 'L' + answer['Row_2'].astype(str)

answer['#not_matched'] = len(df.columns) - answer['#_Match']
```

Output:

```
Row_1 Row_2  #_Match  #not_matched
0    L0    L0        8             0
1    L1    L0        5             3
2    L2    L0        5             3
3    L3    L0        4             4
4    L4    L0        6             2
0    L0    L1        5             3
1    L1    L1        8             0
2    L2    L1        6             2
3    L3    L1        5             3
...
```

Is it what you want?

I'm sorry my solution is very big and no optimal, but I hope it helps.

Comment: This is the concept that I am looking for. Thanks this helps get me to where I need to go

Comment: @SharonM if it is what you want, you can accept the answer. Or I can modify something if you want.